# Reglas de firebase en una tienda online sin usuarios

Tags: javascript, firebase

recién estoy empezando en firebase con las bases de datos y tengo un problema, estoy haciendo una página sobre una tienda online en donde no deseo que haya algún tipo de autenticación, solo deseo que se vean los productos con una breve descripción, pero el problema es que todos los días me llega un correo de firebase diciéndome que mis reglas son inseguras, entonces quería saber como poner mis reglas de manera que sean seguras y solo se muestre la información en mi propia pagina.

Este son las reglas que uso actualmente:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow write: if false; allow read: if true;
        }
     }
}
```

Tengo entendido que están abiertas a todas las personas, mi idea es no guarda por ahora ningún tipo de información sensible en mi base de datos, solo deseo guardar datos de productos sobre mi tienda, como el precio o una descripción evitando todo todo de información sensible, mi objeto es volver las reglas seguras y poder ver los datos desde mi pagina sin ningún tipo de autenticación para ello.

Comment: Quieres hacer una tienda sin usuarios o tus usuarios no se manejan desde firebase?, por cierto, es bueno que censures el codigo que vayas a colocar y pongas en el, el apartado de reglas que usas, de otra forma no podremos ayudarte. ojo, no digo que pongas una imagen y la censures, hablo que copies el codigo de las reglas y te asegures de cambiar la informacion sensible por algo irrelevante.

Comment: por el momento es una  página sensilla y no deseo agregar usuarios, solo deseo que se vea información de los productos, pero firebase me la marca como insegura y quiero saber como volverla segura y poder ver los datos de los productos en mi pagina sin necesidad de una autenticación para ello